# Dialog flow, stuck in a loop conversation, can't trigger cancel event

Tags: google-cloud-platform, chat, dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Hey I'm a new Dialog Flow user, I love the application,  but there is an issue I can't solve. My bot assistent actually is very simple is made by a simple menu with numbers, each number has a intent:

(1) How our business works
(2) Services
(3) Our benefits
(4) Project request
(5) Financial
(6) Meeting and appointments
(7) Contact
(8) Questions and technical support
Default fallback intent
Default welcome intent

Every numbers has a away to come back to the main menu, and a away to ask for a real assistent.

For exemple: Meeting and appointments (6)

> We do weekly video call alignments, as well as you can follow the progress of the project on Trello. If you want to schedule a meeting time, send an email to gorilafreela@gmail.com, inform when, reasons, we use the https://meet.google.com platform for meetings. Type [X] to return to the menu. Enter [A] to request a real answer.

The problem is when the user decide to tap 'A' for request a real assistent. This should end the flow and stop doing a loop. I followed the official Google Dialog flow documentation and to finish the flow they suggested:

1 - Add event: **actions_intent_CANCEL**

2 - **Set this intent as end of conversation**

But even doing this steps, the conversation doesn't stop there. When someone call the real assistent dialog flow answer: What can I help ?, then the user ask his question, however it always go to fallback and the conversation does not finish there. I haven't integrated nodejs with dialogflow yet, but I think it isn't necessary to force a quit conversation. What can I do?

[image]

Comment: AFAIK, to be able to use event **action_intent_CANCEL**, you need to use input phrases like "exit, cancel" ,etc. See [Conversation Exit](https://developers.google.com/assistant/df-asdk/conversation-exits#df_node_exit). How does your agent handle the response when input is "A" it should exit? Do you have some kind of mapping? Also where do you conduct your test? Dialogflow console or Actions on Google console?

Comment: I'm doing tests on what'sApp. I'll try your suggestions and let you know

Comment: @AdrielKirch there's no suggestion in the first comment, it is a question.